# Upgrade to Universal iPhone/iPad application not quite working

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode3.2

I've been playing around with upgrading from an iPhone app to a Universal application, using the handy **Upgrade Current Target for iPad...** menu option.

Everything appears to succeed (although it's really hard to tell, Xcode just whispers success). So I started to change my MainWindow-iPad.xib file that was generated by the upgrade. And that's when I noticed some weirdness.

The window has the same dimensions as *iPhone* not iPad. "Split View Controller" doesn't show up in the Library. It's as though xcode still thinks it's an iPhone application. I've gone into the Target Info and Project Info and set the **Targeted Device Family** to iPhone/iPad, just like the internets told me to; I set the orientation flags, just like the internets told me to.

When I run, buttons don't work that worked on iPhone. I'm using Xcode 3.2.3.

I'd rather not go through the hassle of setting up a new project and moving all the code over. I've noticed building for the app store is extremely fragile and it works for this project so I don't want to mess with it. I say this anticipating an answer with that very solution.

I'm sure there is some obscure setting that's messing everything up, but I'm a total n00b on the iPhone platform, I can't figure out.

Care to enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create a new iPad xib and rename the key in your info plist to that xib?

[image]

Make sure the xib is for iPad.

Comment: Bingo! That works. I had to do add all the junk in IB to make it the main window, but after that it works. Thanks

Comment: Worked very well for me. I had upgraded my app or iPad but the buttons  and table views were not responding, I tried your solution and it worked! Thanks!